# User Reputation tab shows the same data for Month/Quarter/Year view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

- [Month view](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month):

  [image: Month view]
- [Quarter view](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter)

  [image: Quarter view]
- [Year view](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year)

  [image: Year view]
- *Weak* and *All* views are ok.

If that matters, I'm getting the same results, whether I'm logged in or not, both in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Well, it's January.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the first month of the year.

It is also the first quarter or the year.

So, yeah, those three views (Month, Quarter and Year) all show the same. It will change next month ;)

Comment: To add a little clarification (not that it should be needed) - "Quarter" does not refer to any sort of rolling 3 month period, but to fixed 3 month quarters, the first of which is Jan - Mar.

Comment: Does that cry for a feature-request to make it rolling 1 / 3 / 12 month windows...?